# Accessing protected type in a class through a friend - gcc allows, clang doesn't

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

Which compiler is right - or is this a defect in the standard?

GCC compiles the following code, but clang complains:

```
<source>:20:7: error: 'Impl' is a protected member of 'A'
```

Code:

```
template<typename T>
struct WrapperBuilder;

template <typename T>
struct LetMeIn : public T {
    friend struct WrapperBuilder<T>;
};

class A {
protected:
    struct Impl;
};

// without this line, gcc complains too (but I think I understand why)
extern template struct LetMeIn<A>;

template<>
struct WrapperBuilder<A> {

   A::Impl * i; // Clang doesn't like this line
};
```

Thank you.

https://godbolt.org/z/Qa7zZ6

Also, anyone know a workaround for clang that doesn't involve changing `A`?

Comment: I've rolled back the edit you made to add the answer into the Q as that is not where it belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clang is right. Note that gcc has [many bugs](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59002) with access checking in templates.

`Impl` is a protected member of `A`, `WrapperBuilder<A>` neither derives from `A` nor is it a `friend` of `A`.

`LetMeIn` does not bestow friendship in a relevant way. The explicit template instantiation makes `WrapperBuilder<A>` a `friend` of `LetMeIn<A>`, but friendship isn't transitive - that does not make it a `friend` of `A`.

---

`LetMinIn<A>::Impl` works... but very indirectly. You could do it more directly if you want:

```
struct LetMeIn : A {
    using Impl = A::Impl;
};
```

And now it's public.

Comment: Would you want to be my `friend`?

Comment: @Barry probably won't let you access his private parts regardless if you are a `friend` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Clang has it right here.  When you do

```
template <typename T>
struct LetMeIn : public T {
    friend struct WrapperBuilder<T>;
};
```

`WrapperBuilder<T>` becomes a friend of `LetMeIn<T>`.  That means `WrapperBuilder<T>` can access anything in `LetMeIn<T>`.  Since `LetMeIn<T>` inherits from `T` it also means that `WrapperBuilder<T>` can access the `T` part of `LetMeIn<T>` that `LetMeIn<T>` has access to.  It does not mean that `WrapperBuilder<T>` becomes a friend of `T`

To show this

```
template<>
struct WrapperBuilder<A> {

   LetMeIn<A>::Impl* foo;

};
```

Compiles in both clang and gcc since `WrapperBuilder<A>` can access `LetMeIn<A>` members.